# What is the best Library to do Forms in React-Native?

Tags: forms, react-native

I am Learning React Native, Just Found that there is only TextInput Component by Default , Though need to deal with components like DatePicker , CheckBoxes , SelectBoxes etc. What is the Best Suitable Library/ Approach to do this Provided going to Support the App for both IOS and Android.

Answer (score 2):

react-native-element has all the stuff you mentioned.

https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements

But if you look into their source code, they also built with basic `react-native` components, `View`, `Text`, `TextBox`, etc.